# How to flip only one axis of transformation matrix?

Tags: opengl, graphics, computer-vision

I have a 4x4 transformation matrix. However, after trying out the transformation I noticed that movement **and** rotation of the Y axis is going the opposite way. The rest is correct.

I got this matrix from some other API so probably it is the difference of coordinate system. So, how can I flip an axis of transformation matrix?

If only translation I can add minus sign on the Y translation, but I have no idea about opposite rotation of only one axis since all the rotation is being represented in the same 3x3 area. I thought there might be some way that even affect both translation and rotation at the same time. (truly flipping the axis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I'm pretty sure the operation you're looking for is changing coordinate systems while maintaining Z-up or Y-up. In this case, try setting all the elements of the second column (or row) of your matrix to their inverse.

---

This question would be better for the Math StackExchange. First, [a really helpful read on rotation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363652/understanding-rotation-matrices).

The first problem is the matter of rotation order. I will be assuming the XYZ rotation order. We know the rotation matrices for each axis is as follows:

[image: Rotation matrices for each XYZ axis component]

Given a matrix derived from the same rotation order, the resulting matrix would be as follows, where alpha is the X angle, beta is the Y angle, and gamma is the Z angle:

[image: Completed rotation matrix for XYZ rotation order]

You can derive the individual components of each axis angle from this matrix. For example, you can derive the Y angle from `-sin(beta)` using some inverse trig. Given beta, you can derive alpha from `cos(beta)sin(alpha)`. You can also derive gamma from `cos(beta)sin(gamma)`. Note that the same number in the matrix can represent multiple values (e.g. `sin(0)=0` and `sin(180)=0`).

Now that you know alpha, beta, and gamma, you can reverse beta and remake the rotation matrix.

There's a good chance that there's a better way to do this using quaternions, but you should ask the Math StackExchange these kinds of language-agnostic questions.

Answer (score 6):

Much shorter answer: if you are not careful with your frame orientation many things down your pipeline are likely to have a bad hair day. The reason is "parity", a.k.a. "frame orientation", a.k.a. "[right-handedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)" (or rarely left-handedness). Most 3D geometry tools and libraries that work together normally assume implicitly that all coordinate systems in play are right-handed (or at least consistently-handed). Inverting the orientation of just one axis in a coordinate system changes its orientation from right to left handed or viceversa.

So, suggestion for things to check & try in your problem:

- Check that the frame you get from your API is right-handed. You do so
  by computing the determinant of the 3x3 rotation part of your 4x4 transform matrix: it must be +1 or very close to it.
- If it is -1, then flip one if its axis, i.e. change the sign of one of the columns of the 3x3 rotation.
- Note carefully: I said "columns" because I assume that you apply a transform Q to a point x by multiplying as Q * x, x being a 4x1 column vector with the last component equal to one. If you use row vectors left-multiplied by Q you need flip a row.
- If that determinant is +1, you have a bug someplace else.