# Inverting the rotation along the X and the Y axis while keeping Z intact

Tags: swift, matrix, simd, rotational-matrices, transformation-matrix

I have a `simd_float4x4` matrix that is the transformation matrix of a camera.

Inside that matrix, we have the `tx`, `ty` and `tz` that is the translation vector and `0x`, `0y`, `0z`, `1x`, `1y`, `1z`, `2x`, `2y` and `2z`, that is the rotation matrix.

```
┌                  ┐
|  0x  1x  2x  tx  |
|  0y  1y  2y  ty  |
|  0z  1z  2z  tz  |
|  0   0   0   1   |
└                  ┘
```

When I test the rotation matrix I have on a 3D application, I see that the rotations along the X and the Y axis are inverted, while the rotation along Z is correct.

So, on axis X and Y, any rotation the real camera did clockwise is shown anticlockwise.

I need to invert those rotations.

Bear with me because my matrix algebra is rusty.

So, the rotation matrices for the axis are, as stated by the next picture of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103806/316469)

[image]

If I am on the right path, I need to multiply my rotation matrix by `Rx` and `Ry`, right?

If I want to invert the rotations in `X` and `Y`, my `Rx` and `Ry` will be equal to:

```
     ┌             ┐
     |  1   0   0  |
Rx = |  0  -1   0  |
     |  0   0  -1  |
     └             ┘

     ┌             ┐
     |  -1  0   0  |
Ry = |   0  1   0  |
     |   0  0  -1  |
     └             ┘
```

I can multiply `Rx` and `Ry` to obtain the final matrix I have to use:

```
    ┌              ┐
    |  -1   0   0  |
R = |   0  -1   0  |
    |   0   0   1  |
    └              ┘
```

So, all I have to do, is to multiply my rotation matrix by `R` to get the rotations along `X` and `Y` inverted, right?

Nope, the final result is the same... the only thing that happens is that the camera appears to have rotated in Y.

I am using this code

```
import simd

extension simd_float4x4 {

  var rotatedXY: simd_float4x4 {

    let c0 = SIMD3<Float>(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    let c1 = SIMD3<Float>(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
    let c2 = SIMD3<Float>(0.0,  0.0, 1.0)
    let inverse = simd_float3x3(c0,c1,c2)

    let cx0 = SIMD3<Float>(columns.0.x, columns.0.y, columns.0.z)
    let cx1 = SIMD3<Float>(columns.1.x, columns.1.y, columns.1.z)
    let cx2 = SIMD3<Float>(columns.2.x, columns.2.y, columns.2.z)
    let matrix = simd_float3x3(cx0,cx1,cx2)

    let multiplication = matrix * inverse

    var resultado = self

    resultado.columns.0.x = multiplication.columns.0.x
    resultado.columns.0.y = multiplication.columns.0.y
    resultado.columns.0.z = multiplication.columns.0.z

    resultado.columns.1.x = multiplication.columns.1.x
    resultado.columns.1.y = multiplication.columns.1.y
    resultado.columns.1.z = multiplication.columns.1.z

    resultado.columns.2.x = multiplication.columns.2.x
    resultado.columns.2.y = multiplication.columns.2.y
    resultado.columns.2.z = multiplication.columns.2.z

    return resultado
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had this line inverted.

```
let multiplication = matrix * inverse
```

the correct is

```
let multiplication = inverse * matrix
```